# scala test eclipse plugin does not discover test resources

Tags: eclipse, scala, unit-testing

I have a scala project which uses sbt for building/testing/etc. I have a file with unit tests in:

```
$SBT_PROJECT_ROOT/src/test/scala/foo/bar/SomeSpec.scala
```

I also have a test resource in:

```
$SBT_PROJECT_ROOT/src/test/resources/some_test_resource.txt
```

I attempt to acces this file from the unit tests with:

```
import org.scalatest._
import scala.io.Source

class TestFiddleParser extends FlatSpec with Matchers {

  "This unit test" should "find the test resource" in {
    val source = Source.fromURL(getClass.getResource("/some_test_resource.txt"))
    val content = source.mkString
    println(content.take(1000))
  }

}
```

When I am on the commdand line in the $SBT_PROJECT_ROOT folder and run the command:

```
sbt test
```

I can see the first 1000 characters of the test file being printed. Success!

Now I am using eclipse (Scala-IDE) for devolpment. I have eclipse support through `sbteclipse` (https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse) and I run unit tests from within eclipse using the `ScalaTest` eclipse plugin (http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_scalatest_with_eclipse).

When I run this unit test from within eclipse, I get a `null` in the `val source`. Which I believe means the resource was not found.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was actually quite obvious, just run

```
sbt eclipse
```

again **AFTER** adding the the test resource to the `src/test/resources` folder.